# Yii2 dependency custom rule validation

Tags: yii2

I have two input fields consider *A* and *B*, now i want to validate that user can input at least one field that is either *A* or *B* field.

Is there a way to create a rule condition?

Answer (score 2):

> Add like this in rules

```
public function rules()
{
    return [

        [['field_A'],'required','when' => function($model) {

            return $model->field_B == NULL;

        }, 'message' => 'Either field_A or field_B is required.'],

        [['field_B'],'required','when' => function($model) {

            return $model->field_A == NULL;

        }, 'message' => 'Either field_A or field_B is required.'],

}
```

Comment: Hey Sarath. My problem is somehow similar to above question. Can you please have a look on my question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32969883/custom-validation-not-working-yii2-app-basic-yii2

Answer (score 0):

You may create individual rule with use closure. Like that:

```
[['field_a', 'field_b'], function ($attribute, $params) {
                // your code
            }]
```

See more in [doc](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/input-validation.md#inline-validators-)